# validate client id before granting access token with authentication using user credentials oauth2+doorkeeper+rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I have implemented oauth2 token request with username and password but I need to make client_id and secret validation before authentication. If there is no client_id or secret it should return an error message like "Invalid application". Is there any way to make client_id and secret a required field before authenticated with username and password.

Comment: At doorkeeper.rb file, you can apply your condition for validation.

Comment: Hi i've replied you in the other thread at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535306/make-client-id-and-secret-mandatory-in-access-token-request-with-grant-type-pass/28574818#28574818)

Answer (score 1):

you could use before_save at the top of your rb file and check to see if the params exist?

```
before_save :validate_stuff

def validate_stuff
  unless params[:client_id].present? && params[:secret].present?
    raise "Please enter all the info."
  end
end
```

That will fire every time you try to save your object